# Unable to update to Win8.1u1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-update

I am currently on windows 8.1 (`build 9600` if it matters) and when i try to download updates using the "windows update", After selecting packages it gets stuck on downloading updates in both the desktop and ModernUI modes. I downloaded the packages from microsoft site and trying to install `"Windows8.1-KB2919355-x64.msu"`it gives error `0x80240009`

Comment: 0x80240009 = WU_E_OPERATIONINPROGRESS (Another conflicting operation was in progress. Some operations such as installation cannot be performed twice simultaneously.) Don't run the setup several times

Comment: it is not running. i restarted the system and tried it. for some reason it is giving the same error

Comment: upload the file **C:\Windows\Windowsupdate.log** and the folder **C:\Windows\Logs\CBS**

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uhirsqr6w79hne0/WindowsUpdate.log

Comment: Windows thinks you already install updates ("Another CopyUpdateToCache currently in progress")

Comment: cbs.log is already uploading... Any way to clear cache. sfc /scannow says there are corrupt files and was unable to repair them.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/20317g0qo4hfzhd/CBS.log

Comment: the log shows that DISM fails to download the fiels which are corrupted due to a TimeOut. Point to the 8.1 WIM to get the bad files with **/source:wim:c:\install.wim:2 /limitaccess**